# how to scrolldown/focus a tall navbar to active link

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

**I have tall navbar links like this:**

If I click on **404 page** which is deep down then the redirected page opens with tall navbar to by default to the top

[image]

**How can I scroll to navbar window to active link?** Because it is hidden to scroll down and cant assume which page is currently open...

[image]

```
<nav class="sidenav navbar navbar-vertical  fixed-left  navbar-expand-xs navbar-light bg-white" id="sidenav-main">
  <div class="scrollbar-inner">
    <!-- Brand -->
    <div class="sidenav-header  align-items-center">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="javascript:void(0)">
        <img src="{{ asset('brand.png') }}" class="navbar-brand-img" alt="..."> Brand
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-inner border-top border-light">
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link py-1 {{ (request()->is('admin/dashboard*')) ? 'active' : '' }}" href="{{ route('dashboard.index') }}">
            <span class="w-20">
            <img src="{{ asset('icons/dashboardicon.png') }}" width="15"></span>
            <span class="nav-link-text">Dashboard</span>
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</nav>
```

Comment: element.scrollIntoView()

Comment: @PedroLima will you suggest where to put that code at... I have uploaded a piece of code here, that would be helpful :)

Comment: You seem to be using a framework. Is that React? If so, you should add the script in some method that executes right after the page loads. I don't know React :( Also I don't know how much you know of JavaScript but my previous code is just an exemple. `element` would be the element of the nav item you want to scroll into view. You need first to capture it using [getElementById](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) or [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) for exemple and just then invoke `scrollIntoView()`.

Comment: @PedroLima No, its laravel framework, but there is no concern about framework its just work of js or jQuery... Yes I have visited these pages but I don't know where to use these query onto.. so I am stuck here!